# WebPages not working with vNext

Tags: asp.net

How do I get ASP.NET webpages framework to work with ASP.NET vNext? I can't even find the template solutions in the New Project dialog. Not surprisingly though, I cannot seem to find out on Google if it even exists in vNext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET WebPages framework is not currently supported in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (formerly ASP.NET vNext/5.0):

> ## Which to choose?
>
> To be clear, ASP.NET 4.6 is the more mature platform. It’s
>   battle-tested and released and available today. ASP.NET Core 1.0 is a
>   1.0 release that includes Web API and MVC but doesn’t yet have SignalR or Web Pages. It doesn’t yet support VB or F#. It will have these
>   subsystems some day but not today.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/)